# Что делает этот код?

Tags: c#

Здрасьте всем... вот я и исходнике программы нашел очень интересный код... помогите разложить его по полочкам

```
try
{
    using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(this.LCPath + "\\sl.dta", FileMode.Open)))
    {
        byte[] info = new byte[(int)binaryReader.BaseStream.Length - 19];
        this.sl_Header = binaryReader.ReadBytes(19);
        info = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)binaryReader.BaseStream.Length - 19);
        binaryReader.Close();
        byte key = this.sl_Header[10];
        string text = this.Decrypt(info, key);
        string[] array = text.Split(new char[]
        {
            ' '
        });
        this.textBox1.Text = array[1];
        this.textBox2.Text = array[2];
        this.checkBox1.Enabled = true;
        this.checkBox2.Enabled = true;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("sl.dta found but not recognised\r\n" + ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что не понятно то? Открывается на чтение некий файл, в котором есть некий заголовок (первые 19 байт). Считывается в одно место и все остальное содержимое файла в другое (в два предопределенных массива байт). После этого из прочитанного заголовка берут 10-й байт (предполагается что там лежит некий ключ) и преобразуется другим методом данного класса в читабельный формат в виде строки. Похоже, что ключ-строка составной и имеет некую составную структуру с разделителями. Так вот данная строка-ключ "сплитится" и первый и второй результат разделения выводятся в соответствующие "текстбоксы".